# Standard digit database in English and Marathi language

Tags: data-request

Hi i am working on speech recognition project.For testing my algorithm i need a standard digit database in English and Marathi languages i.e. i need an audio file that would be an input of my system. I tried or TIDIGITS standard database but cold not download it. please help me if anyone have it.